# terraform import google_vpc_access_connector.default throws "Error: unknown resource type: google_vpc_access_connector"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm trying to import GCP serveless vpc connector:

```
 terraform import google_vpc_access_connector.default connector-id
```

Then I get error:

```
google_vpc_access_connector.default: Importing from ID "connector-id"...
╷
│ Error: unknown resource type: google_vpc_access_connector
```

I'm on Mac M1 arch so to use terraform I had to install it via `tfenv`, wondering if that might be the cause:

```
brew uninstall terraform
brew install tfenv
TFENV_ARCH=amd64 tfenv install 1.3.4
tfenv use 1.3.4
```

When running `terraform providers` I get:

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google] 3.5.0

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google]
```

Comment: Please add the resource config and the output of `terraform providers` to the question.

Comment: @MattSchuchard updated, by resource config I'm not sure if it's the line added in main.tf containing: `resource "google_vpc_access_connector" "default" {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3.5.0 of the Terraform `google` provider is too old to support the `google_vpc_access_connector` resource. It was added in [version 3.11.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/v3.90.1/CHANGELOG.md#3110-march-02-2020). You would need to update your provider to at least that version to support the resource.

Alternatively: you could switch to the beta version of the `google` provider at that version to support the beta version of the resource, but since patch version updates are safe anyway, then the better course of action would be a patch version update to at least 3.11.0.

A `terraform` block in your config (typically `versions.tf`) may appear like:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 3.11"
    }
  }
}
```